# GestureDetectorCompat not reacting to events

Tags: android, kotlin

In the following code, I do not get any response to touch events when I setup my GestureDetectorCompat. Could it be because I use data binding? If so, do you have any ideas why and how to get around the problem?

```
private lateinit var mDetector: GestureDetectorCompat

private fun setupDataBinding() {
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
    binding.lifecycleOwner = this
}

private fun setupViewListener() {
    mDetector = GestureDetectorCompat(this, MyGestureListener())
}


private class MyGestureListener : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
    private val DEBUG_TAG = "Gestures"

    override fun onDown(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onDown: $event")
        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should override `onTouchEvent()` and `dispatchTouchEvent()` in your activity as below:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    this.mDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
    return super.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(@NonNull MotionEvent ev) {
    super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    return mDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Comment: Solved my problem because the Ticwatch only triggers dispatchTouchEvent while the Samsung Watch triggers both events.